# read in first 3 (out of 8) columns using lapply() in R

Tags: r, import, lapply, read.table, data-processing

I know there have been similar questions answered but i cannot apply them to the following:

I have text files I am trying to read into R:

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = paste0("*_",str_sub(stock1, start = 1, end = -3)[1],".txt"))
```

`filelist`:

```
"20140714_SPY.txt" "20140715_SPY.txt" "20140716_SPY.txt" "20140717_SPY.txt" "20140718_SPY.txt"
```

I now combine these text files using `lapply`

```
datalist = lapply(filelist ,read.table, header=TRUE))
```

but returns the following error

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 1 did not have 8 elements
```

This is what  each `.txt` file looks like:

```
time    price   quantity    board   source  buyer   seller  initiator
20140714T153000 24.82   220     Auto trade          
20140714T153000 24.83   180     Auto trade          
20140714T153000 24.82   100     Auto trade          
20140714T153000 24.8    19971       Auto trade          
20140714T153000 24.81   100     Auto trade          
20140714T153000 24.82   100     Auto trade          
20140714T153001 24.81   500     Auto trade          
20140714T153001 24.8    200     Auto trade          
20140714T153002 24.81   100     Auto trade          
20140714T153002 24.8101 100     Auto trade
```

This is why I only want to read in the first 3 columns: "time" , "price", and "quantity"

I have tried the following but do not work:

```
lapply(filelist,function(x) read.table(x, header=T)[,c(1:3)])


lapply(filelist,function(x) read.table(x, colClasses = c(rep(NA, 3), rep("NULL", 5)),header = TRUE))
```

What does work is if the **individual** files are `cut` but I do not know how to apply this to `lapply`

```
df <- read.table(pipe("cut -f1,2,3 20140715_SPY.txt"))
```

**EDIT:**

This seems to return the desired 3 columns but now need to `rbind` each of the elements

```
datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x) read.table(x, header=T, fill=TRUE)[,1:3])
```

I tried using:

```
datalist1 = rbind(datalist[1],datalist[2],datalist[3],datalist[4],datalist[5])
```

But returns a matrix with 5 elemnts

Comment: Your file is in a faulty format because of the spacing -- R can't figure it out. Using `cut` or other pre-manipulation is your only option.

Comment: You could also try `fill = TRUE` in your `read.table` call.

Comment: @RichardScriven `fill= TRUE` seems to work but it returns as `list`. How do I convert each of the 5 elements so that I can `rbind` it ? Here is what i did: `datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x) read.table(x, header=T, fill=TRUE)[,1:3])`

Comment: Well, yeah.  It returns a list because that's what `lapply` does.  You should just be able to do `do.call(rbind, datalist)` if each list element has the same number of columns.

Comment: @RichardScriven I see, well that seems to have done it! You can put that in the answer so i can give you the points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

**First :**  Try `fill = TRUE` in your `read.table` call.  This will attempt to fill the empty elements with `""` (or `NA` or something else, depending on other arguments)

**Second :**  Instead of

```
datalist1 = rbind(datalist[1],datalist[2],datalist[3],datalist[4],datalist[5])
```

use

```
datalist1 <- do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

to bring the elements together into one data frame.

**Aside :**  It may even be faster to leave off the `[, 1:3]` from your initial read.  Then, call `do.call(rbind, lapply(datalist, "[", 1:3))`... not certain if it would be quicker though.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you have more colnames in your datasets (as shown in the example) and wants to read the first three columns, another option would be:

Starting with 2 files in the working directory

```
 filelist
 #[1] "20140714_SPY.txt" "20140715_SPY.txt"

 lst1 <- lapply(list.files(), function(x) {
 Cols <- rep("NULL", 5)
 Cols[1:3] <- NA
 setNames(read.table(x, skip = 1, header = F, colClasses = Cols), scan(x, n = 3, 
    what = ""))
 })
#Read 3 items
#Read 3 items
 lapply(lst1,head,2)
 #[[1]]
                time price quantity
 # 1 20140714T153000 24.82      220
 # 2 20140714T153000 24.83      180

 #[[2]]
                 time price quantity
 #1 20140715T153000 20.82      220
 #2 20140715T153000 23.83      120
```

Then use

```
 res1 <- do.call(`rbind`, lst1)
```

or

```
 library(data.table)
  rbindlist(lst1)
```